# Запись результат запроса MYSQL в XML файл

Tags: mysql, xml

Здравствуйте,
Задался целью генерить XML файл на прямую из MYSQL минуя PHP, вопрос будет ли это быстрее? и каким образом можно сделать?

Comment: Из комментариев к ответу выяснилось, что автор имел ввиду что-то другое. Необходимо уточнить вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о выполнении запросов из командной строки, то можно сделать, например, так:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM your_table" | mysql --xml -h localhost -u user -pSecret > result.xml
```

Скорее всего, вариант с командной строкой будет быстрее, но, чтобы сказать наверняка, нужно проводить тесты.

Comment: а что это за команды такие? их в shell-exec вызывать?

Comment: Эти команды нужно вводить в командную строку Linux. Если есть на то желание, можете обернуть их в PHP функцию `shell_exec`. Правда я очень-очень сомневаюсь в логичности этого подхода. А вообще, вам нужно четко сформулировать для себя _что именно_ вы хотите сделать, а потом уже искать какое-то решение проблемы.

Comment: Вы же хотели исключить PHP из процесса выполнения SQL запросов -- пожалуйста, эти команды работают вообще без PHP :)

Comment: Я имел ввиду формирование XML средствами PHP и запись в файл делать из MYSQL, а не из PHP. Выполнил запрос shell_exec("mysql --xml -h localhost -u username -p password -e 'SELECT * FROM dp_test' > file.xml"); и мне пустой файл выдало почему то, в чём может быть причина

Comment: Не правильно указали пароль. Пробел между ключом `-p` и самим паролем не нужен. "_Я имел ввиду формирование XML..._" все что вы имели в виду, нужно было отражать в вопросе.

Comment: так я и написал "генерить XML файл на прямую из MYSQL" =) правда в подробностях ограничился